# Single phase motor starting from high leg voltage

Tags: motor, single-phase, delta

Typically stinger voltage is said to be nonuseable, the 208V between a high leg and a bastard tap. [High-leg-delta configuration (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-leg_delta).

But since single phase motors require a phase offset to start anyway, what's to say you couldn't use that high leg instead of a cap start for a 120v single phase motor?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "*... what's to say you couldn't use that high leg instead of a cap start for a 120v single phase motor?*" Voltage, for instance. The series capacitor will drop some voltage so the start winding probably won't even take 120 V.

Answer (score 1):

In a 3-phase induction motor, the phase windings, placed 120° apart, are fed by voltages phase-shifted by 120° to generate a rotating magnetic field to drive the rotor.

Likewise, in a 2-phase induction motor the phase windings would need to be placed 90° apart and fed by voltages phase-shifted by 90°. In fact 2-phase electric power was generated at the turn of the 20th century at Niagara Falls, obviating the need for capacitors to run motors.

Single-phase motors are actually 2-phase motors, with 2 windings 90° apart, and the phase-shift of 90° being provided by a capacitor.

Your suggestion, to use a high-leg delta system to drive a single phase motor without a capacitor, is not practicable in the absence of voltages having a phase-shift of 90°.

***Edited as follows:***

There is absolutely no question vis a vis the phase shift of 90° between the line-to-neutral voltages (120 V) and the high leg voltage (208 V).

[image]

[image]

The only problem would be non-availabilty of the high leg voltage with split-phase consumers.

Availability of the high leg voltage would mean availability of the three-phase system and that would make use of a three-phase motor more valid.

Comment: The highleg voltage is 90deg out of phase with the 120v. If the reference phase is B to A with B being the highleg and the center tap being across A and C, we would expect to see 120v at 120deg and 208v at 30deg

Comment: Andrew Graham, To which terminals of the high-leg delta transformer would the motor be connected? A schematic would help understand your concept.

Comment: See edit. Added schematic.

Comment: Got it! My answer has been edited.

Comment: For sure most consumers in NA would never run across a high-leg in the first place. The only feasible context would be a case where someone is on a highleg and happened to need to run a single phase motor. The only question left, some experimentation required,  is whether there is an advantage to starting with a highleg instead of a start capacitor.